# Check if a date include a certain hour

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I'm working on a fullcalendar project and I was wondering: is there a way in Javascript, with a new Date object, to check if an event include a certain period of hours?

For example: I have this event that start at 8:00 am and end at 05:00pm, I need to see if the period between 12:00am and 01.30pm is included.

**These are my two Dat objects that catch the start and end hour of an event:**

```
const starts = new Date(currentEvents[i].start._i);
const ends = new Date(currentEvents[i].end._i);
```

---

I actually change method so thanks for everyone who tried to give me an answer and spend time for this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Determine Whether Two Date Ranges Overlap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325933/determine-whether-two-date-ranges-overlap)

Comment: _"...I need to see if the period between 12:00am and 01.30pm is included."_ ...compared to what. The UTC Time? The time/hours on the client (local time)?

Comment: I actually found an other way to do what I wanted, but `compared to what.` compare to the date given by the event, I said that

Comment: @Don'tPanic nope, it wasnt. Even if I wanted to go with what I asked I didnt find it useful. thanks anyway

Comment: @Hoscar ... _"...compare to the date given by the event, I said that"_ ... which does not solve the real problem. For any given `Date` object there is a big difference in `getHours` and `getUTCHours` unless one sits on [Greenwich time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenwich_Mean_Time).

Answer (score -1):

if you just compare `Date` objects, you can simply compare the like:

```js
date1 < date2
```

If that is difficult to do that, you could do something like below. This code tests whether the `testPeriod` is completely included in the `targetPeriod`.

```js
const isTimePeriodIncluded = (targetPeriod, testPeriod) => {
  if (targetPeriod.start.getHours() > testPeriod.start) {
    return false;
  }

  if (targetPeriod.end.getHours() < testPeriod.end) {
    return false;
  }

  return true;
};

const mydate_start = new Date(Date.now());
const mydate_end = new Date(Date.now());
mydate_end.setHours(mydate_end.getHours() + 5); //15 ~ 20

console.log(
  isTimePeriodIncluded(
    {
      start: mydate_start,
      end: mydate_end,
    },
    {
      start: mydate_start.getHours() - 2,
      end: mydate_end.getHours() - 2,
    }
  )
);

console.log(
  isTimePeriodIncluded(
    {
      start: mydate_start,
      end: mydate_end,
    },
    {
      start: mydate_start.getHours() + 2,
      end: mydate_end.getHours() + 2,
    }
  )
);

console.log(
  isTimePeriodIncluded(
    {
      start: mydate_start,
      end: mydate_end,
    },
    {
      start: mydate_start.getHours() - 2,
      end: mydate_end.getHours() + 2,
    }
  )
);

console.log(
  isTimePeriodIncluded(
    {
      start: mydate_start,
      end: mydate_end,
    },
    {
      start: mydate_start.getHours() + 2,
      end: mydate_end.getHours() - 2,
    }
  )
);
```

Comment: Thanks you for your answer, but I change method because it was too much complicated as I wanted to do before. But thanks you for your time

Answer (score -1):

There is no in-built function to check if a `Date` falls between 2 given `Date`s, but you could always implement it. The code below checks if the given period clashes with a given time bounds.

```js
const ONE_MINUTE = 60000

/* Bounds */
const boundStart  = new Date() // time now
const boundEnd = new Date(Date.now() + (20)*ONE_MINUTE) // time now + 20mins

/* Period */
const periodStart = new Date(Date.now() + (2)*ONE_MINUTE) // time now + 2mins
const periodEnd = new Date(Date.now() + (10)*ONE_MINUTE) // time now + 10mins

/* Below function checks for time clash */
const isFallsInBounds = (boundStart, boundEnd, periodStart, periodEnd) => {
  if(periodStart <= boundStart && periodEnd > boundStart) {
    return true
  } else if(periodStart > boundStart && periodStart < boundEnd) {
    return true
  } else {
    return false
  }
}


console.log(isFallsInBounds(boundStart, boundEnd, periodStart, periodEnd))
```

Comment: Thanks you for your answer, but I change method because it was too much complicated as I wanted to do before. But thanks you for your time